# vuejs: how to pass a prop data when using render function for dynamic template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
const CustomSelect = {
  template: `
    <select v-model="value" required>
      <option :value="option in question.options">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    <select>
  `,
  props: ['value', 'question']
}

const DynamicTemplateComponent = {
  props: ['value', 'questions'],
  render(h){
    return h({
      components: {
        CustomSelect 
      },
      props: ['value', 'questions'],
      template: `
        <form>
          this is a dynamic template <custom-select :question="questions[0]" v-model="value[0]"/>, the template string may change, <custom-select :question="questions[1]" v-model="value[1]"/>
        </form>
      `
    }) 
  }
}


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
     DynamicTemplateComponent
  },
  data(){
    return {
      questions: [
        {
          options: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
        } ,
        {
          options: [1, 2, 3, 4] 
        },
      ],
     answers: Array(2)
    } 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <dynamic-template-component v-model="answers" :questions="questions"/>
</main>
```

In this example, a component with dynamic template needs to pass props data from root vue instance to the children components

how can I make it work so that when user select value in `CustomSelect`, the event(`v-model`) can be proped to the root component correctly?

Thanks a lot for anyone help!

Answer (score 2):

You should define proper types for props, then instead of mutating the prop emit an input event that will trigger the model to update, then emit again from the render function.

```js
const CustomSelect = {
  template: `
  <select v-model="model" multiple required>
    <option v-for="option in questions">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
  `,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([]) // value for multi-select must be array
    },
    questions: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([])
    }
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
  }
}

const DynamicTemplateComponent = {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([])
    },
    questions: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([])
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h('form', ["this is a dynamic template ", h(CustomSelect, {
      props: {
        questions: this.questions,
        value: this.value
      },
      on: {
        input: (value) => {
          this.$emit('input', value)
        }
      }
    })])
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    DynamicTemplateComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [{
          options: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        },
        {
          options: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
        },
      ],
      answers: [
        [],
        []
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/* ignore - used to reduce SO's console output */
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <pre>{{ answers }}</pre>
  <dynamic-template-component v-for="(question, index) in questions" v-model="answers[index]" :questions="question.options" :key="index" />

</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Your solutions work perfectly when the template is fixed, but may little hard for a dynamic template. However, inspired by your answer, I finally figure out how to do this without handling `$parent` directly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I got a stupid but worky solution for this, by using `$parent`

```js
const CustomSelect = {
  template: `
    <select :value="value" @change="updateValue" required>
      <option :value="option in options">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
    </select>
  `,
  props: {
    index: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data(){

    let { options } = this.$parent.$parent.questions.find(question => {
      return question.index == this.index;
    });

    let value = this.$parent.$parent.value[this.index];

    return {
      options: options,
      value: value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(e){
      let answers = {...this.$parent.$parent.answers};
      answers[this.index] = e.target.value;
      this.$parent.$parent.$emit('input', answers)
    }
  }
}

const DynamicTemplateComponent = {
  props: ['value', 'questions'],
    render(h){
      return h({
        components: {
          CustomSelect 
        },
        props: ['value', 'questions'],
        template: `
          <form>
            this is a dynamic template <custom-select :index="0"/>, the template string may change, <custom-select :index="1"/>
          </form>
        `
      }) 
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    DynamicTemplateComponent
  },
  data(){
    return {
      questions: [
        {
          index: 0,
          options: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
        } ,
        {
          index: 1,
          options: [1, 2, 3, 4] 
        },
      ],
      answers: Array(2)
    } 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
  <dynamic-template-component v-model="answers" :questions="questions"/>
</main>
```

If you got more elegant solutions for this, please share your answer, thanks a lot!