# Vuejs get dynamic form values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, web-component, buefy

I have select and input component with made by buefy. Everything is ok till I realize how can I get the data.

I'm sort of new on vuejs. So I will be glad if you help me out.

I'm getting dynamic form from backend

**So my question is** how can get values these inputs and submit to backend again with getOffer() methot.

Here is my codes;

Input.vue

```
 <template>
  <b-field :label="fieldLabel">
    <b-input
      :name="inputName"
      :type="inputType"
      :maxlength="inputType == 'textarea' ? 200 : null"
    ></b-input>
  </b-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Input",
  props: {
    inputType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "text",
    },
    inputName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    fieldLabel: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container is-max-desktop wrapper">
   
            <div v-for="element in offer" :key="element.id">
              <Input
                v-model="element.fieldValue"
                :value="element.fieldValue"
                :fieldLabel="element.fieldLabel"
                :inputType="element.fieldType"
                :inputName="element.fieldName"
                v-if="element.fieldType != 'select'"
                class="mb-3"
              />
              <Select
                v-model="element.fieldValue"
                :fieldLabel="element.fieldLabel"
                :options="element.infoRequestFormOptions"
                :selectName="element.fieldName"
                v-if="element.fieldType == 'select'"
                class="mb-3"
              />
            </div>
            <b-button type="is-danger" @click="getOffer()">GET</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Select from "../components/Select.vue";
import Input from "../components/Input.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      offer: [],
    };
  },
  components: {
    Select,
    Input,
  },
  methods: {
    getOfferForm() {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `/GETDYNAMICFORM`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          this.offer = response.data;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$buefy.toast.open({
            duration: 3000,
            message: "oops",
            position: "is-bottom",
            type: "is-danger",
          });
        });
    },
    getOffer() {
      console.log(this.offer);
      
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getOfferForm();
  },
};
</script>
```

Example Dynamic Form Response like;

[
{
"id": 58,
"fieldLabel": "Name Surname",
"providerLabel": "Name Surname",
"fieldName": "nmsrnm",
"fieldType": "text",
"fieldValue": null,
},
{
"id": 60,
"fieldLabel": "E-mail",
"providerLabel": "E-mail",
"fieldName": "e_mail_60",
"fieldType": "email",
"fieldValue": null,
},
{
"id": 2,
"fieldLabel": "Budget",
"providerLabel": "Budget",
"fieldName": "bdget",
"fieldType": "select",
"fieldValue": "",
"infoRequestFormOptions": [
{
"id": 1,
"orderNum": 0,
"optionValue": 0,
"optionText": "Select",
"minValue": null,
"maxValue": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"orderNum": 1,
"optionValue": 1,
"optionText": "10-30",
"minValue": 10,
"maxValue": 30
}
]
}
]

Comment: What is your question? It's unclear what you want to ask here

Comment: @JasonLandbridge sorry for this. I edited my question.

Comment: you should pass in a model, use it on the input, then emit an `input` event on change, i.e `this.$emit('input', this.value)`, which then it will update the model you passed in, example with a select https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053868/vuejs-how-to-pass-a-prop-data-when-using-render-function-for-dynamic-template/68055246#68055246